# Angular, setting up a karma test for a filter

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

Trying to set up a test for a filter here, here is what I have

the filter:

```
 angular.module('myApp')
.filter('discount', function(){
return function(input, discount){
    if (input) return  input*(discount);
 };
});
```

The test

```
describe("Unit: discount", function() {

var filter

beforeEach(function(){
module.apply('myApp');

inject(function($injector){
  filter = $injector.get('$filter')('discount');
});
});

it('should filter the parameters passed', function(){
expect(filter(1, 0.5)).toBe(0.5);
});
});
```

The error I am recieveing:

```
  PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X) Unit: discount should filter the parameters passed FAILED
   Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: discountFilterProvider <- discountFilter
```

The intended effect would be passing the filter 1 as the input and 0.5 as the discount, and expecting back 0.5. I am brand new to working with this and am stuck so I could use a little help. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it just `module('myApp')` instead of `module.apply('myApp')`?

Answer (score 0):

The error :

```
Unknown provider: discountFilterProvider <- discountFilter
```

Is telling you that $injector cannot find discountFilter.
The module myApp is not loaded correctly.

You should try this syntax for before each :

```
var filter;

beforeEach(module('myApp'));

beforeEach(function (){
    inject(function($injector){
        filter = $injector.get('$filter')('discount');
    });
});
```